# Promesa Pending

Tags: javascript, fetch, promesas, peticion

Estoy intentando obtener la data de esta peticion, pero al ejecutarlo la promesa se queda en pending

```
const res = fetch('https://api.cualquuera').then(res=>console.log(res.json()))
```

Intento colocarle otro. Then a ver y tampoco. El resultado esta encerrado asi: [[PromiseResult]]
Nose si estara bloqueado para acceder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actualización:
Se ha modificado la URL original por deseo del OP.

---

Prueba con esto, tal como dice la [documentacion de fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

```
const res = fetch('https://api.cualquiera/api/v1/pais')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

A mi me está devolviendo esto:

```
[{
  Id: 1,
  IdT: "CO",
  Pais: "COLOMBIA"
}, {
  Id: 2,
  IdT: "BR",
  Pais: "BRASIL"
}]
```

Si tan solo haces esto:

```
const res = fetch('https://api.cualquiera/api/v1/pais')
.then(response => console.log(response))
```

veras que te devuelve un objeto Response, el cual, entre la lista de sus propiedades, tiene un método denominado `json()`:

```
  json: function json() {
    [native code]
},
```

por lo tanto, en el siguiente `then` lo capturamos con la variable `data` y lo mostramos en consola:

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Gracias amigo mi error era que como lo enviaba a consola no me leia la funcion. Json en el otro then

Comment: Vale manito igual muchas gracias